# Тема в Google Chrome(Flatpak) не меняется вместе с системной

Tags: linux, google-chrome, fedora, flatpack, flatpak

Установил flatpak версию google chrome и обнаружил, что при при переключении в настройках со светлой темы на темную оформление chrome не меняется. Причем на rpm версии такая же проблема, но использовать собираюсь flatpak. Причем в настройках принудительно могу включить темную тему, но хочется чтобы тема определялась автоматически согласно системной теме. И у остальных приложений flatpak проблем с этим нет. Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Использую fedora 36.

Answer (score 0):

Троеточие - настройки - внешний вид - использовать GTK+

Comment: Было бы слишком просто, не работает

Comment: Гребаный флетпак. попробуй деб/рпм версию